# Remove related element from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of image data like this:

```
[other-image] => Array
        (
            [img] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1526973657.jpg
                    [1] => 1526973661.jpg
                    [2] => 1526973665.jpg
                )

            [path] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ../post-upload/1/
                    [1] => ../post-upload/1/
                    [2] => ../post-upload/1/
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [thumb] => Array
                (
                    [0] => thumb_1526973661.jpg
                    [1] => thumb_1526973665.jpg
                    [2] => thumb_1526973668.jpg
                )

        )
```

Now I want to delete an image and it's all related data from sub arrays. (path, type, thumb data)

This is how I tried it in `php`:

```
  $delkey = '1526973657.jpg';
  if(in_array($delkey, $_SESSION['other-image']['img'])){
      $imgkey = array_search($delkey, $_SESSION['other-image']['img']);
      if($imgkey) unset($_SESSION['other-image']['img'][$imgkey]);
  }
```

But problem is I can't delete related data from other arrays. 
Can anybody tell me how to do this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `!==false` after `array_search()` because it may return first index i.e. 0 in some cases, so your condition will not executed. And regarding delete related data from other arrays, you have to unset other data related to that key.

```
if($imgkey!==false){
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['img'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['path'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['type'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['thumb'][$imgkey]);
    }
```

Comment: yes its working. but I cant get the logic.. can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php - Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise. In your example, you are searching '1526973657.jpg' and it is on `0` index of the array so array search will return `0`. if you write `if($imgkey)` , it will not go inside if condition so data will not be removed even it existed in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Is the related data has same key with img?
If they are same, I think you only need to add some codes to delete other data like the way was used to delete img.

```
if($imgkey) unset($_SESSION['other-image']['path'][$imgkey]);
if($imgkey) unset($_SESSION['other-image']['type'][$imgkey]);
if($imgkey) unset($_SESSION['other-image']['thumb'][$imgkey]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keys in img sub-array are related with the same key(index) in sub-arrays(path, type and thumb, you can also unset those keys. e.g.

```
$delkey = '1526973657.jpg';
if(in_array($delkey, $_SESSION['other-image']['img'])){
    $imgkey = array_search($delkey, $_SESSION['other-image']['img']);
    if($imgkey){
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['img'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['path'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['type'][$imgkey]);
        unset($_SESSION['other-image']['thumb'][$imgkey]);
    }
}
```